# how to get IndexPath

Tags: iphone

in iphone application.

I'm trying to get indexPath.row value to do something  on the basis of  row selected in programmatically created tableview.

Can someone please tell me  why is  the indexPath.row value is not coming correct. It's some thing like  21487...3?

```
NSUInteger nSections = [myTableView numberOfSections];
NSUInteger nRows = [myTableView numberOfRowsInSection:nSections];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: nRows inSection:nSections];
NSLog(@"No of sections in my table view %d",nSections); 
NSLog(@"No of rows in my table view %d",nRows);
NSLog(@"Value of selected indexPath Row %d", indexPath.row);
```

Thanks,
Aaryan

Answer (score 7):

The rows and sections of an `NSIndexPath` are arrays, and so start at 0 rather than 1. Therefore, the number of rows (or sections) in an `NSIndexPath` is actually 1 greater than the index of the last one.

Try

```
NSInteger lastSection = nSections - 1;
NSInteger lastRow = nRows - 1;    
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRow inSection:lastSection];
```